# Ubuntu Virtual Host with two domains weird redirection

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

Have an Ubuntu server that have two virualhost conf files:

magento.conf and
syberparts.conf

outletfactoryparts.com is magento.con
syberparts.com is syberparts.conf

Issue is with Syberparts.com. When going to the domain, it redirects to outletfactoryparts.com:90 for some reason.

I used to have to listen to port 90 before moving the DNS to the new server, but after removing port 90 and adding 80, seems to have issues.

syberparts.conf below:

```
    ServerAdmin sales@outletfactoryparts.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/syberparts


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    <Directory /var/www/html/syberparts>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerName syberparts.com
    ServerAlias www.syberparts.com
```

Looking into ports.conf, I am only able to find ports 80 and 443. No 90.

I am trying to have syberparts.com to display syberparts.com and go to its own public root directory within the Ubuntu server. Let me know if I could supply with more information or try out a few things - thanks!

Comment: There's a 302 redirection, probably in an htaccess file on your site.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Wow, after some searching it was app specific redirection that was specified in the database. Can't believe I overlooked it. Thanks HJPotter92 for the pointer.